How to add second element to a list in a request body using builder() in java?
I have a problem with creating a request using dto. I used singletonList to have one element in items list. What can I do to add second item to my items list in request body?
request dto:

public class RmaNewRequestDTO {
    @JsonProperty("return")
    Return returnData;
    Order order;
    Store store;
    List<Items> items;

    (...)

    @Data
    @Builder
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    public static class Items {
        int orderItemId, qtyRequested, resolution;
    }
}

request body:

        RmaNewRequestDTO rmaNewRequest = RmaNewRequestDTO.builder()
                        (...)
                .items(Collections.singletonList(RmaNewRequestDTO.Items.builder()
                        .orderItemId(itemOrderId.get(0))
                        .qtyRequested(firstProduct.getQuantity())
                        .resolution(RESOLUTION_ID_REFUND)
                        .productSku(firstProduct.getSku())
                        .ean(firstProduct.getEan())
                        .build()))

                        (...)

                .build();


Call .items(...) with a list containing all elements you want? What's the actual problem?

I have a request body with one item now (containing orderId, qty and resolution). I would like to have a body with two different items.

.items(yourListContainingTwoItems)?

You can put @Singular on any collection field. Lombok will now create two adder methods which allow you to add elements to the collection, either one by one or several at once.
In your case, it looks like this:
public class RmaNewRequestDTO {
...
    @Singular List<Items> items;
...

You can now use it as follows:
RmaNewRequestDTO.builder()
        .item(myFirstItem)
        .item(mySecondItem)
        ...

Note that both methods only add elements, even the method that has a collection-type parameter. If you want to reset (empty) the list, use the clear method.
